# Using "if / else" in CSS to change language

Tags: php, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

Does anyone know how to use condition in CSS?
I'm using PHP CMS.

The thing is that I have a variable "Post Title" that sometimes may be in RTL language.
So I want some sort of CSS code or any other solution that can detect if the language is arabic and set the direction to RTL, else LTR.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use attribute selectors.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Comment: it is impossible to use conditions in CSS. you can use conditions in your programming language and then change the style accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to generate the CSS on the fly, why not include the a stylesheet relevant to the content like so:

```
<?php

    if($style_1){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_1.css">
    }else{
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_2.css">
    }

?>
```

***There are several ways you can achieve this, but in my opinion, the above is definitely the better of the methods***

Answer (score 0):

Try this, good example on how to style RTL blogs, but I'm not sure if its compatable with your CMS.

http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/styling_right-to-left_text_with_css_on_a_multi-lingual_site/

OR

You can have something e.g.

```
<?php if($lang="en"){?>
body .title{left to right styles}
<?php }else{?>
body .title{right to left styles}
<?php }?>
```

Just a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

i think best way is write 2 different CSS, on for rtl , and another for ltr

and put it in your php code in `<header></header>` html tag

```
if($lang['direction'] == "ltr" )
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ltr.css">';
else
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rtl.css">';
```